# Add to a cart : create and populate a custom object in apex

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, sobject

In a lightning component, I want that when I click a button, it create a new custom object (a virtual cart) and populate it with the select item. 
I have 3 custom object: the articles__c, the cartline__c and the cart__c. 
A cart can have 0 to * cartline__c.

A cartline__c is linked to article__c with master detail relation, and is linked to cart with a master detail relation too.

So in a component I have the Id of the article in parameter, I want to pass it to the controller apex that create and populate the cart. Here is the component that display the article :

```
<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}" />
<aura:dependency resource="markup://force:navigateToComponent" type="EVENT"/>
<aura:attribute name="idArt" type="String" />
<aura:attribute name="article" type="Article__c" default="{'sobjectType': 'Article__c'}"/>
<!-- The id is {!v.idArt} -->

<div class="details">
  <h1>{!v.article.Name}</h1>
  <div id="btnRetour">
    <button onclick="{!c.addToCart}" class="btnPanier">Add</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

the js controller :

```
doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
    var articleId = component.get("v.idArt");
    var action = component.get("c.findById");
    action.setParams({
        "articleId": articleId
    });
    action.setCallback(this, function(a) {
            component.set("v.article", a.getReturnValue());
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
},

addToCart : function(component, event, helper){
    var articleId = component.get("v.idArt");
    var action = component.get("c.addToCart");
    action.setParams({
        "articleId": articleId
    });
}
```

And here is the start of the addToCart method in the apex class :

```
@AuraEnabled
public static void addToCart(String articleId){
  Cart__c cart = new Cart__c();

  List<Cartline__c> linelist= new List<Cartline__c>();

  Cartline__c line = new Cartline__c();

  line.Article__c = articleId;
  update line;
  linelist.add(line);

}
```

I don't know how to start and how to create a cartline (that has an `article` field that reference the article__c object and a `cart` field that reference the cart object) with the article, and then add this cartline to the cart ?

Comment: If I understand it correctly, you want to create CartLine which requires cart id as well as article id. currently you have article id. What you have thought about cart id, from where will it come. In addToCart you havn't enqueued your action.

Answer (score 1):

As your requirements - you need a cart to be created before adding to it cartLines.

so you can changes your apex controller like this:

```
@AuraEnabled
public static void addToCart(String articleId){
    // 1. create and insert the new cart, and get the new cart id from DB
    Cart__c cart = new Cart__c();
    insert cart; // now cart.Id would be filled with the newly created id


    // 2. create list (of 3 cartLines for example) - to insert them all together as 1 list:
    List<Cartline__c> linelist = new List<Cartline__c>();
    Integer i;
    for (i=0; i<3; i++) {
        Cartline__c line = new Cartline__c();
        line.Article__c = articleId;
        line.Cart__c = cart.Id;
        // you can add data to all your fields here

        linelist.add(line);
    }

    // 3. now add all your cartLines with 1 DML 
    update linelist;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @ItaiShmida, but I don't understand how I use the cart.Id. Do I have to declare the lineList like that : `List<CartLine__c> listLine = new List<CartLine__c>(Cart__c = cart.Id)` so I am sure that the cart lines belongs to the right cart ?

Comment: Sorry, you are right - I forgot, and added now to my code the line: `line.Cart__c = cart.Id;`